# jQuery - Allow only specific email domain to register

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a registration form in 2 specific user type called `usertype1` and `usertype2`.

1. `usertype1` - Allow all email domains
2. `usertype2` - Only specific email domains

In `usertype2`, list of domains:

- schoolA.com
- schoolB.com
- schoolC.com

This is my code:

```js
(function() {
  $("#email").attr('placeholder', 'Please put your student email');
  $("#usertype").change(function() {
    if($("#usertype").val() == "usertype1") {
      $("#email").attr('placeholder', 'Please put your student email');
      email = $("#email").split('@').slice(1);
      var domains = ['schoolA.com', 'schoolB.com', 'schoolC.com'];
      if ($.inArray(email, domains) ! == 1) {
        $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    } else {
      $("#email").attr('placeholder', 'Please put your student email');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="school" id="usertype">
  <option value="usertype1">School A</option>
  <option value="usertype2">School B</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="email" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I tried my code but it won't work because missing argument or something.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Your line of code `if ($.inArray(email, domains) ! == 1)` has an extra space. It should be `if ($.inArray(email, domains) !== 1)` :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thank you. fixed it, but it's still doesn't work. JS console said :Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ! :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. Replace it with `$.inArray(email, domains) == -1`. That should do it ;)

Comment: Done, placeholder didn't appear. I tried to change 2 selected option value and the placeholder and submit button didn't function. Am I override the event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in the code snippet:

- function is wrapped in `()` but never executed, that's why "placeholder didn't appear" -- no code is running. Suggestion: wrap function in `$()` so that it will be executed once page is loaded.
- `$("#email")` does not have a method as `split()`. I think it should be `$("#email").val().split()` here.
- `.slice(1)` returns an array, which is incorrect. It should be a plain `[1]` here to get the domain name of email.
- The inner function which checks userType only runs when `#userty` selector is changed. It is better to make it run when page is initialized / `#userty` selector is changed / `#email` input value changed.
- jQuery selector is overused. It is better to use selector once and store the result in variable. It is more efficient.

After fixing these issues, it is good to go. Here is a code snippet that works:

```js
$(function() {
  var $email = $("#email");
  var $userType = $("#usertype");
  var $submitButton = $(':input[type="submit"]');

  $email.attr('placeholder', 'Please put your student email');
  $userType.change(checkUserType);
  $email.keyup(checkUserType);
  checkUserType();

  function checkUserType() {
      if($userType.val() == "usertype1") {
      $email.attr('placeholder', 'Please put your student email');
      var emailDomain = $email.val().split('@')[1];
      var domains = ['schoolA.com', 'schoolB.com', 'schoolC.com'];
      if ($.inArray(emailDomain, domains) < 0) {
        $submitButton.prop('disabled', true);
      } else {
        $submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
      }
    } else {
      $email.attr('placeholder', 'Please put your student email');
      $submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="school" id="usertype">
  <option value="usertype1">School A</option>
  <option value="usertype2">School B</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="email" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/L2jyvc56/1/) is also made for reference.

Comment: You're the best! Perfect explanation for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you mean by "jQuery selector is overused. It is better to use selector once and store the result in variable. It is more efficient" ? Is it about nested if else?

Comment: @rootnel no, it's not about nested if-elst. What I mean is: `$(...)` statement is used too much -- this statement will search element in page, which will cost some CPU resource. Thus, if there are 2 identical `$(...)` statement, the same search is delivered twice, which is a waste.

Comment: Noted @shaochuancs. Thank you for the explanation. :)